# Xcode Error armv7s

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Here is the error message I get when i try to run my application;

`Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_CLLocationCoordinate2DMake", referenced from:
      -[DodgeDirectionsViewController viewDidLoad] in DodgeDirectionsViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

How do I correct this error? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include CoreLocation.framework in your project :)

**Edit**:

Steps:

Go to project Targets -> Build Phases -> Click on '+' button and add 'CoreLocation' framework :)